# Importing CSV file to create point layer

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, csv

[image]I have a CSV file with following fields:

- Nodename
- Nodeid
- Latitude
- Longtitude
- Elevation

I am using Python console in QGIS to automate this. How should I write so that point with latitude, longtitude and elevation are maked as point layer?
I have tried with below code, but I  am getting error.

```
uri = "/home/priti/Desktop/MTP work/nodeinput.csv?\
type=csv&xField=Longtitude\
&yField=Lattitude\
&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Nodes', "delimitedtext")
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: If you screenshot is showing what you are doing of course it will not work. You need to change path to file+filename and the name of lat and long field

Comment: I didnt  get you .

Comment: I am woking on Ubuntu system . There is no such C drive here i think

Comment: But your screenshot shows that you try to access C

Comment: Hi, uri="/home/priti/points.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=Longtitude&yField=Lattitude&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,'Points','delimitedtext')
layer.isValid()   I tried this but still i am getting layer as False . Please help i cant start if i am unable to import it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry #Qgis2
#from qgis.core import QgsProject #QGIS3

uri = "file:///C:/Test/points.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=Longitude&yField=Latitude"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,'Points','delimitedtext')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer) #Qgis2
#QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer) #QGIS3
```

[image]

Comment: QgsProject' object has no attribute 'addMapLayer' Getting this Error

Comment: Yeah This time there was no error, but i cant see points

Comment: any idea ? why i cant see points :(

Comment: Do you get the 'Points' layer in Layers tree? Is the attribute table empty?

Comment: My Layer Panel is empty

Comment: any more suggestion Please

Comment: @ps1 - What is your `uri`? Maybe an issue with the path?

Comment: uri = "/home/priti/Desktop/MTP /nodeinput.csv?type=csv&xField=Longtitude
&yField=Lattitude &spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no" '

Comment: Any issue with Path ? I have renamed my points.csv to nodeinput.csv

Comment: I have added image of my current Qgis Env please check

Comment: Is there really a space after 'MTP' in the path? Please use the right path to your file if you want it to work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82007/discussion-on-answer-by-bera-importing-csv-file-to-create-point-layer).

Answer (score 2):

You say you are trying with the python console, but if you want to try with stand alone python, this does the trick:

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import Point, mapping
import csv


driver = 'ESRI Shapefile'
schema = {'geometry': 'Point', 'properties' : {'Nodename': 'str', 'Nodeid': 'int'}}
pointlayer = fiona.open("test.shp", 'w', driver=driver, schema=schema)
with open("test.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skip header
    for row in reader:
        geom = Point(int(row[2]), int(row[3]), int(row[4])) # Considering the order of elements that you gave
        pointlayer.write({'geometry': mapping(geom), 'properties': {'Nodename': row[0], 'Nodeid': row[1]}})

pointlayer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip QGIS and go directly to OGR2OGR.

https://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html
use -lco X_POSSIBLE_NAMES="" -lco Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=

ogr2ogr airports.shp airports.csv -dialect sqlite  -sql "SELECT MakePoint(CAST(longitude as REAL), CAST(latitude as REAL), 4326) Geometry, * FROM airports"